# data.table and base in R - meaning of `|`

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, radix

I came across a command in **R** that I struggle to understand, maybe someone can enlighten me?

```
sample[, AGG := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = agg]
  sample[, AGG_NEW := AGG]
subset = seq_len(nrow(sample))
sample[subset, val := (AGG_NEW >= (value) - 1)) | val ]
```

My interpretation so far is this:

From data.table `sample`, take all rows `subset` (which has been defined), in those rows mutate the column `val` then i am not sure what is happening....

what does the `|` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line,

```
library(data.table)
sample[, AGG := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = agg]
```

we specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols` i.e. `agg` (perhaps it is a object name with multiple columns),

Then use `Reduce` to get the rowwise sum (`+`) of the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`).

In the second step, the column 'AGG' is copied to create the 'AGG_NEW',

```
sample[, AGG_NEW := AGG]
```

then we are passing an index i.e. sequence of rows in `i` (not sure why it is needed here), then create the 'val' as a logical vector

Even without the 'subset' the code should work because 'subset' showed is the full sequence of rows of original dataset

```
sample[,  val := (AGG_NEW >= (value) - 1)) | val ]
```

The `|` signifies the `OR` operator i.e. either  the lhs  OR the rhs condition is met, then it returns `TRUE` or else it is `FALSE`

Comment: lets say that `val` is boolean `FALSE`. That means val will be set to `TRUE` only if `(AGG_NEW >= (value) - 1))` is true, correct?

Comment: @Nneka Yes, it is right. The `|` option is to make sure that already existing TRUE remain TRUE

Comment: that already existing TRUE remain TRUE? i am not sure i understand this correctly...

Comment: @Nneka Suppose you have `v1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE); v2 <- c(2, 3, 2); v1|(v2 > 2)`